# UnsupportedOperationException on Endpoint.publish() with Jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jetty, jax-ws

I am getting the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: !DelegatingThreadPool
```

With this code:

ServerStart

```
  Server server = new Server(4433); //Jetty

  System.setProperty(
          "com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider",
          "org.eclipse.jetty.http.spi.JettyHttpServerProvider");

  JettyHttpServerProvider.setServer(server);

  //error occurs here
  Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:" + 4433 + "/buecherservice", new BuecherServiceImpl()); 

  //not reached code
  server.start(); 
  server.stop();
```

WebService with Interface:

```
@WebService 
public interface BuecherServiceIntf //Interface

@WebService
public class BuecherServiceImpl implements BuecherServiceIntf
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Your service runs in a own container. Hence you have to choose a different port for your server instance compared to your webservice.

Comment: I have changed the port to 'new Server(8080)' but still i get the same error

Comment: sorry it is not the same error, i get now 'jetty server is not bound to port 4433'

Comment: Then my comment maybe wrong. Spring handles the webservices in a own container. Probably your solution doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Server server = new Server(4433);
```

to the following which is required for http-spi

```
Server server = new Server(new DelegatingThreadPool());
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
connector.setPort(4433);
server.addConnector(connector);
```

Comment: The DelegatingThreadPool requires an Executor as argument? Can you provide me with some help here?

Comment: Try the following int  corePoolSize  =    5;
int  maxPoolSize   =   10;
long keepAliveTime = 5000;

Executor threadPoolExecutor =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                corePoolSize,
                maxPoolSize,
                keepAliveTime,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
                );